# How to add field in accommodation section (Products Plugin)?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, settings

I have this section when I'm adding product in my website.

[image]

I want to add a new field. e.g. I want to add "Bathroom" field name and a textbox for input.

I'm checking if there's a settings to add a field on the section. These are the settings for other infos but I think there's no settings to add a field for the accommodation section when adding a product.

[image]

What can I do?

P.S: I'm using a casa theme (wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simple solution for you if you don't have any option to add another field. Then Install "Advanced custom fields (ACF)" plugin add a custom field and assign that field to post type = Product . Then call that variable to product page or where ever you want to output that variable value.
Cheers!

Comment: I'm using casa theme by wordpress and the accomodation section is from casa theme. I'm researching if there's a settings for this w/o installing plugin to add a new field.

Comment: then assign field to that taxonomy. If it is not in the product. Then assign filed to that specfic taxonomy and and call that variable on that taxonomy page for output.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do u mean on assign field to taxonomy? Where do I assign a field?

Comment: have a look at this plugin page. you will find out how to make custom fields  etc. for more in depth information checkout documentation of this plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/screenshots/